# Flatten a Perl array of hashes

Tags: perl

Currently have this demonstration code:

```
use 5.012;
use Data::Dump;

my $AoH = [
    {a => "aval"},  #exactly only one key-value
    {b => "bval"},  #for each
    {c => "cval"},  #array element
];

dd $AoH;

my @arr = map { each $_ } @$AoH;
dd @arr;
```

it works and produces my wanted result

```
[{ a => "aval" }, { b => "bval" }, { c => "cval" }]
("a", "aval", "b", "bval", "c", "cval")
```

The question is: is correct the the `map { each $_ }` construction, or it is possible to do it with "another way"?

Comment: This `each $_` is introduced in Perl 5.14, so you may want to change that `use 5.012;` to `use 5.014;`.

Comment: @Borodin The changed title is sure "cleaner" than my original messy one, but I asked here after a searching google and honestly I searched only keywords like "convert hash to array" and similar, and _never_ used the word "flatten". Maybe other perl beginners will search "convert" and not for "flatten" too. At least this comment will be indexed, so:  Convert array of hashes to array in perl. ;)

Comment: You are welcome to remove my edit if you wish

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just dereference the hashrefs:

```
my $AoH = [
    {a => "aval"},  #exactly only one key-value
    {b => "bval"},  #for each
    {c => "cval"},  #array element
];

# Flatten the hash refs
my @arr = map { %$_ } @$AoH;
```

I'd advise against using [`each`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/each.html) in that context.  From `perldoc`:

> Starting with Perl 5.14, `each` can take a scalar `EXPR`, which must hold reference to an unblessed hash or array. The argument will be dereferenced automatically. This aspect of `each` is considered highly experimental. The exact behaviour may change in a future version of Perl.

Comment: omg. how easy it is (now) :) why didn't get the idea myself. :( Thank you. :)

Comment: Your advice is valid. You'll see `each $_` fail by repeating the last two lines (`my @arr = map { each $_ } @$AoH; dd @arr; my @arr2 = map { each $_ } @$AoH; dd @arr2;`). The quoted paragraph is irrelevant. Using `each %$_` won't help at all.

Answer (score 0):

> is correct the the map { each $_ } construction,

Not exactly. In your specific case, it will do what you want. However, as pointed out by @ikegami, this will introduce a subtle bug in your code, do what you did twice, you will see the problem. Every hash has a internal iterator, and this iterator will be reset only after you exhausted that hash, and read it once more. (It is similar to `feof()`.)

Additionally, `each $_` only available since Perl 5.14 or later, for early versions, you need to use `map { each %$_ }`.

However, the REAL problem is that there is no need to use `each`, you could use `map { %$_ }`, in list context, hash will return a list made up of its key-value pairs.

> or it is possible to do it with "another way"?

Also yes, you could use `foreach` and `push`, like this:

```
push @arr, %$_ foreach @$AoH;
```

However, this is basically the same as your method.

Comment: I wouldn't call it correct. It leaves the hashes partially iterated. Duplicate the last two lines of the program, and watch them give different output.  (`my @arr = map { each $_ } @$AoH; dd @arr; my @arr2 = map { each $_ } @$AoH; dd @arr2;`)

Comment: @ikegami You are correct. There is no need to use `each`, and using it also introduces subtle bug.